# Gnome-calendar not running

Tags: gnome-calendar

```
android@inspi:~$ gnome-calendar
Command 'gnome-calendar' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install gnome-calendar  # version 3.30.0, or
sudo apt  install gnome-calendar  # version 3.38.1-2
See 'snap info gnome-calendar' for additional versions.
android@inspi:~$ sudo apt install gnome-calendar
[sudo] password for android: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-calendar is already the newest version (3.38.1-2).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libbrlapi0.7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 185 not upgraded.
android@inspi:~$ gnome-calendar
Command 'gnome-calendar' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install gnome-calendar  # version 3.30.0, or
sudo apt  install gnome-calendar  # version 3.38.1-2
See 'snap info gnome-calendar' for additional versions.
android@inspi:~$
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt reinstall gnome-calendar`

Comment: `185 not upgraded`: Upgrading the system first would be a good idea. That may solve the issue with gnome-calendar.